# Excel VBA - copy cell if value matches list and ALSO is in array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare a list in sheet 1 to a longer list in sheet 2 (I have this part working). I then am trying to implement a second statement where, IF the value on sheet 1 is found on sheet 2, I want to see if the associated value in another column on sheet 2 is one of 8 specific values (which I've stored in an array set in the script). If the value of that cell matches one of the items in the array, I want it to then add the match with its array value to a list in a separate sheet. Below is what I have so far (please pardon how Frankenstein-ed this code looks!):

```
Sub status()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, c As Range
Dim vStages As Variant
Set sh1 = Sheets("FLEX")
Set sh2 = Sheets("WIP")
Set sh3 = Sheets("Report")

lr1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr1)
Set rng2 = sh2.Range("B2:B" & lr2)
Set rng3 = sh2.Range("D2:D" & lr2)

vStages = Array("Shipped", "Delivered", "Complete - Design", "Delivered to USPS", _
    "Delivered", "Complete - Fulfillment", "Complete - Inventory", "Complete - Mailing")

With sh3
    .Range("C1") = "Finished but not Invoiced"
End With

For Each c In rng1 
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, "*" & c.Value & "*") = 1 And rng3 = vStages Then
        sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)(2) = c.Value
        sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)(2) = rng3.Value

End If

Next
End Sub
```

I know the problem is occurring at the "And rng3 = vStages Then" part but I don't know how to properly set that part up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ooh, ooh, ooh!  I learned this one yesterday!!  Change `rng3 = vStages` to `Not IsError(Application.Match(rng3.Value, vStages, 0))`

Comment: That seems to be half working! I'm now running into a problem though where the stage name that it posts next to the value all says the same thing, which is also not a value from the array. It might be a problem with the line sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)(2) = rng3.Value ?

Comment: Ahhh - I hadn't noticed that `rng3` wasn't a single cell - that it's really just all possible values.  `rng3.Value` will just be `[D2]` from the "WIP" sheet.  Looking at your code further, it looks like you are going to have to change your code to actually `Find` the appropriate row on sheet "WIP" that you are wanting to look at.  (Doing a `Count` tells you that it exists, but not **where** it exists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test whether the value of `rng3` exists in the array `vStages` you can use

```
... And Not IsError(Application.Match(rng3.Value, vStages, 0)) Then
```

`Application.Match` will return an error if the lookup value does not exist in the array so, if no error is returned, it means the value **does** exist in the array.

---

I have updated your code to use a `Find` to locate the row on the "WIP" sheet that matches the data on the "FLEX" sheet:

```
Sub status()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range
    Dim vStages As Variant
    Dim FindCell As Range
    Set sh1 = Sheets("FLEX")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("WIP")
    Set sh3 = Sheets("Report")

    lr1 = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr1)
    Set rng2 = sh2.Range("B2:B" & lr2)

    vStages = Array("Shipped", "Delivered", "Complete - Design", "Delivered to USPS", _
        "Delivered", "Complete - Fulfillment", "Complete - Inventory", "Complete - Mailing")

    With sh3
        .Range("C1") = "Finished but not Invoiced"
        For Each c In rng1
            'Search on WIP for the value from FLEX
            Set FindCell = rng2.Find(What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            'See if we found it
            If Not FindCell Is Nothing Then
                'Ensure that the value only appears once in WIP
                If rng2.FindNext(FindCell).Address = FindCell.Address Then
                    'Check the stage is one of the ones we are after
                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(FindCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, vStages, 0)) Then
                        'Store details
                        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)(2) = c.Value 'Or maybe "= FindCell.Value" ?
                        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)(2) = FindCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Modified to process every match in WIP:

```
Sub status()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range
    Dim vStages As Variant
    Dim FindCell As Range
    Dim FirstFind As String
    Set sh1 = Sheets("FLEX")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("WIP")
    Set sh3 = Sheets("Report")

    lr1 = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr1)
    Set rng2 = sh2.Range("B2:B" & lr2)

    vStages = Array("Shipped", "Delivered", "Complete - Design", "Delivered to USPS", _
        "Delivered", "Complete - Fulfillment", "Complete - Inventory", "Complete - Mailing")

    With sh3
        .Range("C1") = "Finished but not Invoiced"
        For Each c In rng1
            'Search on WIP for the value from FLEX
            Set FindCell = rng2.Find(What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            'See if we found it
            If Not FindCell Is Nothing Then
                FirstFind = FindCell.Address
                'Loop through all occurrences
                Do
                    'Check the stage is one of the ones we are after
                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(FindCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, vStages, 0)) Then
                        'Store details
                        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)(2) = c.Value 'Or maybe "= FindCell.Value" ?
                        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)(2) = FindCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    End If
                    Set FindCell = rng2.FindNext(FindCell)
                    If FindCell.Address = FirstFind Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @AlisterM - answer updated to use `Find`.  I have done limited testing (based on what I **think** your data might be).

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thank you so much! I didn't really know that was how Count worked vs Find, so it's really good to know the difference and be able to see them both compared here.

Comment: I think I spoke too soon. It appeared to be working correctly but I actually went through to compare and make sure it wasn't missing any entries from the data and I'm finding that it's correctly pulling SOME, but not touching others. For instance, it correctly matched T-90379 (Shipped) but skipped over T-90345 (Shipped). The cells are formatted the same, there's no extra spaces, I've copied and pasted the stage name directly into the code to account for any typos, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: @AlisterM And "T-90345" only appears once in column B of WIP?

Comment: Yes, that entry only appears once. Some of the data entries start with hyphenated letters (such as T-12345 or G-09876) but the numbers themselves should never repeat (ie there will never be T-12345 and G-12345). However, there is the occasion when there's a "two-part" entry and it will be designated as part A and B in the WIP (such as 12345A and 12345B). In that instance, there will only be "12345" listed on the FLEX list, but both 12345A and 12345B will appear on the WIP list and we'd need to see both of them, if applicable.

Comment: (a) Temporarily change the code by replacing `Set rng1 = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr1)` to something like `Set rng1 = sh1.Range("A497")` (use whatever cell address is applicable to "T-90345" on the "FLEX" sheet).  Then step through the code line-by-line to see why it doesn't get down to the "store details" part.

Comment: (b) If you have multiple instances of the data entries in WIP, your original method of saying "only process if Count = 1" would have ignored them.  That's why I included the `If rng2.FindNext(FindCell).Address = FindCell.Address Then` statement - to exclude entries which occurred twice.  (That statement would only be True if it appeared once.)  So you now want **all** records for those type of data to be selected?

Comment: I discovered the problem with it "skipping" the entry- it was completely my mistake because the line wasn't in the FLEX list at all and I had totally forgotten to even check that in the first place. Sorry for that confusion on my part!

As for part b, I hadn't figured that part into my solution so I apologize for not bringing it up sooner. Yes, I would need for it to be able to select all records for those type of data, if they're listed more than once.

Comment: The list only shows one of the entries, and the WIP list is actually being updated to change the cell value. ie: T-90379A and T-90379 are both on the WIP list. Running the updated code posts T-90379A in the report list, and then changes the "A" to a "B" on the WIP list so that there are two entries of "T-90379B" (I used your commented = FindCell.Value towards the end to help me see what was going on a bit better)

Comment: @AlisterM As far as I can see, the code in my answer never updates anything other than on the "Report" sheet.

Comment: Would the line `FindCell = rng2.FindNext(FindCell)` have anything to do with it? I tested the actual value-writing part of the code and temporarily removed the part where it posts the data values into the report, and the entry in the WIP list still ended up changing.

Comment: @AlisterM DOH!!!! - yes it would - it needs to be `Set FindCell = rng2.FindNext(FindCell)` - I'll update the answer.  Sometimes I hate that VBA allows `.Value` to be a default property - without the `Set` it was interpreting the statement as `FindCell.Value = rng2.FindNext(FindCell).Value`

Comment: I've THOROUGHLY tested it and in combination with the rest of the script that I had to put together for the whole process, and I'm excited to say that everything is running smoothly now! :) Thank you so much for your help, it was a great learning opportunity and I'm hoping that next time I have to work on something similar I'll be able to use this knowledge as a platform to build on.

Comment: @AlisterM - That's the ideal outcome for SO - a user who not only has been given a fix for their problem but has also learned something in the process :)